# Is defining permission at Asset's property level possible using Hyperledger Composer Access Control Language?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have an asset X with 4 properties xp1, xp2, xp3, xp4.
I have 2 participants P1 & P2. 
I would like Participant P1 to read only xp1 & xp3 properties whereas participant p2 can read/write xp2 property.

How do I write access control rule for this?
As per [documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/acl_language.html), we can write rules at the Object level but not at the property. 
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as per Rocketchat -> https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=72gQcE9WBGig5YiBL  @praveencastelino currently not possible for property (field) based access control in ACL runtime -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/983 which you've commented on and something that is in plan.

A workaround might be to have two assets that are --> relationships to the parent asset X  (each new asset has eacn of xp1/xp2 or xp3/xp4) and then P1 or P2 as appropriate  would have READ access to that data only,  in your ACL rules.